# pandas pivot table default behaviour

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe which looks like :

```
col1 col2      col3 col4 
   0    fst    4    7
   0    snd    5    8
   1    fst    6    9
```

I apply:

```
 pd.pivot_table(df, index='col1', columns='col2', aggfunc='count', fill_value=0.0)
```

output:

```
       col3        col4
       fst   snd   fst  snd
index 
0      1     1      1    1
1      1     0      1    0
```

Expected output:

```
       fst   snd 
index
0      1     1     
1      1     0
```

Why columns have multiindex?

Comment: Because you have another two columns `col3` and `col4`, you don't need `pivot_table` just `pd.crosstab(df.col1, df.col2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the `values`

```
out = pd.pivot_table(df, index='col1', columns='col2', values = 'col3',aggfunc='count', fill_value=0.0)
```

Also in your case ,do `pd.crosstab`

```
out = pd.crosstab(df.col1, df.col2)
```